# Oracle: Overwrite values in a column with the longest string

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m running into a problem.

Say, I have columns called “C1, C2, C3....” in a table. I’d like to use the longest string in C1 to replace every other cells in C1 column without disturbing other columns.

I tired several ways but I cannot get my Oracle code run. Could someone please show me a sample code to do this problem? I typed my question using a cellphone so I apologize for not showing you my code. But I think my description is fine... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> update test set
  2    dname = (select max(dname)       --> MAX fixes TOO-MANY-ROWS because ACCOUNTING 
  3             from test               --  and OPERATIONS have same length
  4             where length(dname) = (select max(length(dname))
  5                                    from test
  6                                   )
  7            );

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 OPERATIONS     NEW YORK
        20 OPERATIONS     DALLAS
        30 OPERATIONS     CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, GROUP BY]**

Another example is based on a different table, which reflects what you described in a comment. The `DEPTNO` (*department number*) is used to "group" employees, and I'm going to update the `JOB` column value to the longest job name within that department.

Query is similar to the previous one; it just *joins* appropriate columns (DEPTNO) throughout code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
           KING       PRESIDENT  --> the longest in DEPTNO = 10
           MILLER     CLERK

        20 ADAMS      CLERK
           FORD       ANALYST
           JONES      MANAGER    --> as long as ANALYST, but MAX(JOB) will return this value
           SCOTT      ANALYST
           SMITH      CLERK

        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN   --> the longest in DEPTNO = 30
           BLAKE      MANAGER
           JAMES      CLERK
           MARTIN     SALESMAN
           TURNER     SALESMAN
           WARD       SALESMAN
```

Update and the result:

```
SQL> update test t set
  2    t.job = (select max(t1.job)
  3             from test t1
  4             where t1.deptno = t.deptno
  5               and length(t1.job) = (select max(length(t2.job))
  6                                     from test t2
  7                                     where t2.deptno = t1.deptno
  8                                    )
  9            );

14 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      PRESIDENT
           KING       PRESIDENT
           MILLER     PRESIDENT

        20 ADAMS      MANAGER
           FORD       MANAGER
           JONES      MANAGER
           SCOTT      MANAGER
           SMITH      MANAGER

        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
           BLAKE      SALESMAN
           JAMES      SALESMAN
           MARTIN     SALESMAN
           TURNER     SALESMAN
           WARD       SALESMAN
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! But I forgot to add one condition that some values in C1 have the same value in C2. And I actually need to find the “local longest” string and overwrite other values in C1 within each C2 group...Could you please further give an example?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my message by adding another example; have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions.  Oracle has a very convenient functionality with `keep`:

```
select max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by len(col1) desc) over () as col1,
       col2, col3, . . .
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update t
    set col1 = (select select max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by len(col1) desc) over () as col1
                from t
               );
```